# What's the fastest/easiest way to get Forgotten Souls?

Tags: diablo-iii

What is the fastest/easiest way to get [*Forgotten Souls*](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/forgotten-soul)?

Right now I have quite a few legendary materials, but not a single Forgotten Soul, so I can't craft any of these level 70 legendaries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found that doing rifts with a good party is the fastest way.  The rift guardian has a pretty high chance of dropping a soul and legendary drops are boosted while in rifts.  There is no other good way really of getting souls other than rifts.

**As of the latest patch (2.1) you can no longer do the following as everyone needs to contribute a key to enter the rift:**

An even faster way now is to join the Rift it Forward community (assuming you have enough keystones to open rifts) to quickly farm Rift Guardians as well as to gain blood shards for gambling purposes.

With this community, you can gain hundreds of souls very quickly.

Comment: I'd add that if you're really desperate for souls, gambling with Kadala for any 5-shard item (since that is the lowest cost) has a chance of generating a legendary for you. Like any legendary, it will often be trash and thus salvageable for a Forgotten Soul. And since the best way of getting shards for gambling is doing rifts, it ties right back into rifting being the best option.

Comment: Agreed, Rift it Forward is awesome to fast farm forgotten soul. I saw many people complaining about it on the forum, saying it was cheating but as long as blizzard allows it, go for it :D

Answer (score 29):

There are several ways for getting Forgotten Souls :

- Doing rifts : The rift guardian has a high chance of droping a Forgotten Soul. Pick the higher Torment level in which you can complete the rift quickly (2-3 min max). Farming in party will help you farm faster and in higher Torment resulting in more Forgotten souls. Moreover, the bloodshards you get from the Rift Guardian allow you to gamble at Kadala, significantly increasing your legendary "drop" rate.
- Killing an [Odious Collector](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Odious_Collector)
- Salvaging unwanted legendaries (*my trick to get "trash legendaries" is to really wish for something good, then the next 50 legendaries are going to be worthless*). If you really need Forgotten Souls and have plenty of other crafting materials, you can use Kanai's Cube to upgrade rares into a legendaries and salvage them.

I usually clear T10 rifts and salvage every legendaries that is not usefull for my character. I currently have more than 8000 unused Forgotten Souls.

Comment: Rifts are really the best method, since you get 100% increased chance of finding legendaries aswell, giving you more to salvage.

Answer (score -1):

if ur on switch and have 2 switches for some reason you can create 2 profiles on both of them in non-seasonal mode, save your data to the cloud on ur main switch and download it on ur spare.then just drop all the legendaries for the 2nd profile, stash them and repeate until your 2nd profile has a full stash.save your 2nd profile to the cloud, download it on your main switch then have them play with your character on your main switch and drop all the legendaries. salvage all thosee lagendaries on your main account then repeat.

Comment: srry thought that that was comment section